# Certificate answer and keystore are identical

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I´m trying to sign my JAR file with a certificate from Thawte. When I´m trying to run

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias alias -file C:/signed/MyCert.cer -keystore C:/signed/file.jks

I just get the error

> **Certificate answer and keystore are identical**

Does anyone know what this might mean?

For some time ago I created a csr file that was sent to Thawte for confirmation. After a while they return an answer with a certificate. When I now tries to sign my JAR file I get the above error. Can something been lost between these steps?

Kind regards / H

Comment: The real question is why are you exporting? You should be importing. There's no need to export a signed certificate. That's one of the many benefits of getting it signed.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong sentence.

Comment: hi @hgerdin did you solve this? I have the same problem.